# Send x11 linux app to windows xming server from linux

Tags: linux, windows, xorg, xming

I know from Windows with xming server and putty x11 forwarding enabled an ssh putty session can open linux GUIs on Windows. This flow is initiated from Windows.

Is there a way to initiate the connection from Linux to have an app like gcalctool connect to xming on Windows to show its panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was set the DISPLAY variable in bash e.g.

```
export DISPLAY=10.0.1.30:0.0
```

Where 10.0.1.30 is the IP address of the Windows xming server and then add the IP address of the linux machine to `C:\Program Files\Xming\X0.hosts`.

After that in the same bash session with the `DISPLAY` variable I launched a GUI program like gcalctool or gedit and it popped up on the Windows xming server.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1) Set up SSH X forwarding on your host PC.

Uncomment the following in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseForwarding yes
```

2) Open and set up Xming on your client Windows PC.

3) Open putty. Go in Connection --> SSH --> X11 and tick "Enable X forwarding" and enter display location as *localhost:0.0*

4) Login into the server using SSH. Note that this may take time.

5) Run any GUI app using bash.

Comment: This is what I know how to do, not what I'm looking to do...

Comment: Just tried this, and `X11UseForwarding` is not a valid SSHD configuration setting. If you add it to your config, and then restart, ssh won't start up. (Version: `OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017`.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing [openssh](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH), [freesshd](http://www.freesshd.com/), or some other ssh server on your Windows machine and login to it from your linux machine. Alternatively, install something like [Winexe](https://sourceforge.net/p/winexe/wiki/Home/) or psexec on your linux device and log in that way.
  From there, simply launch putty via the command line and log back into your linux installation. If that doesn't work, try something like [Cygwin's](https://www.cygwin.com/) ssh utility.
  Just to clarify- the idea is that you ssh into your windows machine from linux, and then ssh back into the linux machine from that remote terminal with x11 forwarding turned on.

Comment: Didn't need SSH. However SSH would be a nice layer of security on top of what I was trying to do. I'm not sure how to add SSH when I'm initiating it from Linux (see my answer for what I'm doing).